# Why isn't Bayek's ring finger removed for the hidden blade?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

As far as I know the primitive hidden blades in Assassin's Creed needed the removal of the finger to accommodate its use. That was what was shown in the first Assassin's Creed game -  the one featuring Altair for the first time.

Then in Assassin's Creed 2 it is shown that with the specific design of Leonardo da Vinci, a hidden blade could be crafted for Ezio that would avoid dismemberment.

So chronologically Bayek is much more ancient that Altair and by that very fact the hidden blade is supposed to be much more ancient and should in fact need the removal of the ring finger for its accommodation.

But this is not the case as shown in AC Origins.

Isn't that a plot hole?

Comment: (the devs figured out how to render the blade without clipping in the hand), Seriously though, this could be explained more subtly elsewhere

Comment: @Rapitor agreed the devs no longer care much about the plot of ac games. But its still something that should be considered

Comment: does this site have a problem with questions about the game's plot ?

Comment: @ng.newbie While this site does allow asking about a game's plot or lore, there are some users who dislike these type of questions

Comment: @ng.newbie Lore question have always been contentious on the site because some users believe lore has nothing to do with the actually playing the game itself, and should therefore be off-topic. However, lore questions are totally acceptable on the site - don't worry about one or two downvotes.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the finger-removal thing was more ceremonial than anything (considering it's done even after it's rendered unnecessary). So maybe it was never necessary, but it was a nice way to show your dedication to the Assassins (or someone made that up after accidentally cutting their finger off)?

Comment: This is "Origins", so this will show the origins of the brotherhood, so there won't be a ceremony yet

Comment: Didn't Leonardo explicitly mention that the missing ring finger was never really necessary, and that he infers that giving up your ring finger was ceremonial (as a matter of showing dedication to the cause), disguised as a supposed necessity to have the hidden blade work? (Please no Origins spoilers if you reply, I've only just started playing the game)

Answer (score 26):

Without exposing any spoilers, your concerns are explained during cutscenes in the game.  Namely, during the *[Aya](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/Aya)* and *[End of the Snake](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/End_of_the_Snake)* main quests.

If you don't mind spoilers, here is a full explanation:

> When Bayek obtains the hidden blade at the end of the *[Aya](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/Aya)* main quest he has all of his fingers.  There is a cutscene whereby Bayek is testing out the blade.  Aya opens Bayek's hand to prevent self-injury when using the blade. Bayek loses his finger during *[End of the Snake](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/End_of_the_Snake)*. It is the main quest after *[Aya](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/Aya)*.  You will see a cutscene when assassinating Eudoros whereby the hidden blade cuts Bayek's finger off.

This [**YouTube clip**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whmrSPFi_gg) shows the *[End of the Snake](http://ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-origins/End_of_the_Snake)* mission.  Skip to the third minute to see the key cutscene.

Comment: Yeah, it is much older by the time line that the brotherhood's "protocol| or "procedures".
There are one thing that most probably connects to the reason of why the ring was needed to be removed - in one of the scenario scenes, in the begining, where Bayek lost his finger. I found this moment strongly connected to the one that you've mentioned.